# Trying to create a delay function whilst performing other functions, using Timer.h libraries. Arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, functions

I am having a compilation error saying invalid useof template-name 'Timer without an argument list.

[image: arduino code]

Comment: First: What is your font dude? XD Second: Please don't show images of code here. Instead you should copy and paste the code as text into your question. Then select the code and click on the `{}` button to format it correctly. And third: You should include the complete error message (as text like the code) into your question. Also provide links to the Timer library, that you are using.

Comment: Second: Which `timer` library are you talking about? Have you looked at its doc/examples ?

Comment: i love the font ... what is its name?

Answer (score 0):

Read, play with, and understand the Arduino **BlinkWithoutDelay** basic example.
*Understand* means learn that it does not only apply to blinking, but to any time related action without blocking the main loop().

It's better learning the basics than using libraries in a wrong way.

Comment: thank you for your avid response, it was my first time posting here. i will Read, play with, and understand the Arduino BlinkWithoutDelay.